# Laravel 5.3 Pulling comments from the fields of a DB table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Simple question here:
In laravel 5.3 how would I pull the comments from a database table? Is there a clean way of doing it using some of the out-of-the-box features that laravel provides??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are just starting with laravel then go through official documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: While eloquent is powerful it makes reference to this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#creating-columns which also references 'composer require doctrine/dbal'. Having gone through doctrine/dbal's internal structure you'll find that there are far more methods that allow you to interact with a table's structure in a DB than eloquent. While the implementation can make all the difference in terms of efficiency, the answer provided below was to demonstrate a way to grab what he's looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5.2-5.3, as far as I know, comes with a built-in package called doctrine that allows you to interact with a lot more within a database and it's tables than eloquent. I believe the framework members will eventually add more to the system so you can make more dynamic use of a DB and tables etc.

For the time being this is how I implement accessing the structure (comments included) of a database table:

```
$settings = SomeModel::where($items_match)->get(); //Making use of Eloquent

$columns = DB::connection('database_name_here')
            ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
            ->listTableDetails('table_name_here');

foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {

            if ($comments[$key] = $columns->getColumn($key)->getComment()) {

            }
        }
```

It's fairly clean and get's the job done. The only downside I see is it's a double hit to the DB which I'm thoroughly against, I'm working on a way to combine the 2 implementations in laravel so that it's only 1 query doing both jobs.

Comment: Would this also get me other bits of information? Like a fields datatype??

Comment: Yes you can. If you're using sublime Text 2 or 3 you should be able to highlight the "getComment" method, right click it and then select "Go To Definition" you'll be able to find where the method is and browse through all the other public function methods that will give you the access you're looking for within a specific DB table.

Comment: From what I'm seeing it looks like eloquent is mostly used for data and model manipulation, could that be why they incorporated the use of this doctrine package to give DB structure access??

Comment: Most likely, yes. I'd reach out to them to find out more about future plans for eloquent... or.. when you're up for it, dive into eloquent's structure and see if you can add clean, professional features to eloquent. Then make a pull request on laravel/framework's github and see if they'll accept... This comes with time and experience though so I'd recommend getting more familiar with laravel before looking to add or change something in the vendor folders.