# How to get table description (comment) from Doctrine connection

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine, database-schema

I know the description and information of a table can be obtained with [a raw query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082755/accessing-table-comments-in-sql-server). But how can I get this information with Doctrine?

The following Laravel code sample retrieves table information but it does not include the table description.

```php
$details = $connection->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
    ->introspectTable('table_name');

$result = [
    'columns' => $details->getColumns(),
    'foreignKeys' => $details->getForeignKeys(),
    'comment' => $details->getComment(),// ========> this line don't return any value
    'options' => $details->getOptions(), 
    'name' => $details->getName(),
];
```

Comment: This isn't a Laravel question, and certainly nothing to do with Eloquent. You're working entirely with Doctrine here, which is at a lower level.

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424596/laravel-5-3-pulling-comments-from-the-fields-of-a-db-table

Comment: @miken32 yes. laravel orm use Doctrine.

Comment: @Adi I want to get table comment not table columns comment.

Comment: Also just a quick note to say your code works fine with MySQL, so this must be something specific to SQL Server

Comment: @miken32 so this should be mentioned in the title. which has been deleted by you.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I used Laravel's Query Bulider to get the table descriptions.

```
public function getTableDescription($connection, $schema, $table)
    {
        $fields = [
            'td.value as description',
        ];

        $info = $connection->table('sysobjects as t')
            ->select($fields)
            ->join('sysusers as u', 'u.uid', 't.uid')
            ->leftJoin('sys.extended_properties as td', function ($join) {
                $join->on('td.major_id', 't.id');
                $join->where('td.minor_id', 0);
                $join->where('td.name', 'MS_Description');
            })
            ->where('t.type', 'u')
            ->where('u.name', $schema)
            ->where('t.name', $table)
            ->first();

        return $info->description;
    }
```

Is there an easier idea to not use raw query (tsql)?